# Shapefile in ggplot : Impossible to fill polygons with the values of a column

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile

I'm trying to make a plot of a shape file, where the polygons are fill by the value of one column.

I used this code :

```
Groups <- readOGR(".", layer="Grid_GroupMean1")
ggShape <- ggplot(data = Groups, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, fill = Groupr))+ geom_polygon() +geom_path(color = "white")
print(ggShape)
```

The level of the factor "Groupr" is 5 (O,1,2,3,5,6).
There is a lot of Zeros in this factor. I don't know if it's problematic.

The plot of the shape file works without the function "fill".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYIcy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3tS1.png)

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Screen shots of data structures are not particularly helpful.

Comment: Finally, when I was searching to create a shape file for exemple, I found by myself a solution with the function fortify() : 
"function from ggplot2 transforms data from shapefiles into a dataframe that ggplot can understand" [http://www.kevjohnson.org/making-maps-in-r/]
`Groups <- fortify(Groups, region="Groupr")`